# How can GA4 new vs established be (not set)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have created a GA4 exploration with a single dimension (New vs Established) and a single metric (sessions).

A small number of sessions have the 'New vs Established) dimension as '(not set)'

This is only a small number (around 0.5% of all sessions) so isn't going to significantly impact reporting, but I am intrigued as to how this happens.

Unlike other properties, this is a binary - you're either one thing or the other... so how can some sessions be neither?

I thought this might potentially be related to certain events, but it appears not. This is showing for a relatively similar share of events under session_start, page_view, and custom events.